# Making sense of this iptables http proxy config

Tags: iptables

I've never touched `iptables` before and I'm trying to understand exactly what these three lines do. I have `ip_forward` switched on and I know the end effect is that all traffic on `eth0` is forwarded except TCP Port 80 traffic from `192.168.0.2`

```
os.system("iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT")
os.system("iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE")
os.system("iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2)
```

I've been reading the [man](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) page but it's still really cryptic to me. I've never been introduced to this before. I'm hoping someone could explain this in a clearer way.

I understand that `-A` is to append a new rule and `-t nat` is to indicate we're dealing with the `nat` table. I can't make sense of the rest however.